# How to write __annotations__ (scene property) in new scene?

Tags: python, properties

I have a scene with custom properties, written in a class, I am now able to access the values of these properties,
I would like to know how to write these values in a new scene. For example:

This is the properties:

```
class MySceneProperty(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    my_bool: BoolProperty(default=false)
    my_int: IntProperty(default=0)
    my_float: FloatProperty(default=0.0)

def register():

    bpy.types.Scene.scene_prop = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MySceneProperty)
```

I would like to create a new scene and use the previous parameters, as they could be changed by the default value, so the approach would be.

```
def my_function(self,context):
    first_scene = bpy.context.scene

    ###get attributes:
    for key in first_scene.scene_prop.__annotations__.keys():
        first_attributes = getattr(first_scene.scene_prop, key)

    ###new scene creation:
    new_scene= bpy.data.scenes.new("New scene")    
    context.window.scene = new_scene

    #Here I would like to set the attributes of the previous scene but I 
    #don't know how to do it

    ###set attributes???  (this obviously produces an error)

    for key in new_scene.scene_prop.__annotations__.keys():
        setattr(new_scene.scene_prop, key) = first_attributes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Free you mind and think simple: `new_scene.scene_prop.my_bool = first_scene.scene_prop.my_bool`

If however you need to batch-set properties from a list of strings, like the `__annotations__.keys()` method returns, you can use Pythons `setattr` and `getattr` methods:

```
for s in first_scene.scene_prop.__annotations__.keys():
    setattr(new_scene.scene_prop, s, getattr(first_scene.scene_prop, s))
```

So in the end, your function from above could be turned into:

```
def my_function(self, context):
    first_scene = bpy.context.scene

    ### new scene creation comes before the loop:
    new_scene= bpy.data.scenes.new("New scene")    
    context.window.scene = new_scene

    ### copy attributes from source to target scene:
    for key in first_scene.scene_prop.__annotations__.keys():
        source_attribute = getattr(first_scene.scene_prop, key)
        setattr(new_scene.scene_prop, key, source_attribute)
```

Comment: Thanks aliasguru for the reply! this was my first thought, but I really have many properties, and I'm continuing to add them, so I would have to compile all the properties every time, I'd like to have a "faster" way of having all the properties and precisely I came across this ".__ annotations __. keys ():" "getattr ()" which gives me all the attributes I need, I just want to understand how to set them on the new scene without having to compile 1x1

Comment: @Pastrokkio updated my answer

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error:  TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: @Pastrokkio Was typing this on my phone in a rush this morning, I have updated the code now, should work

Comment: All this is fantastic! I thank you very much for the time you spent for me, it seems to work perfectly and will save me a lot of time because it will automatically go inside the properties without having to enter 1x1, I think this thing is useful to many people, it is little about this situation.

Comment: have difficulty using this method on blender 2.79, __annotation__ is an invalid parameter, is there a solution? do I have to post a new question?

Comment: @Pastrokkio __annotations__ have been introduced with Blender 2.80, so they don't exist in 2.79. Before that I used to deal with the `bl_rna` methods. `bpy.context.scene.scene_prop.bl_rna.properties.keys()` etc. should get you started there. But this really is a different question, so please ask a new one in case.

Comment: thanks you are very kind, I posted a new question, I received an answer but I have not tried yet with the suggested method, the question is here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153764/how-to-get-set-attributes-scene-property-in-blender-2-79/153794#153794